foregroundservice datasync type is being closed after removing mainactivity
My problem is that the instance that starts my foregroundservice does not start forever, but terminates after a couple of seconds when the mainactivity "turns off" and the app closes in one of the foregroundservice methods. As I understand it, the system for some reason terminates the foregroundservice itself along with all the intents that it starts, because when I added an infinite loop to the main intent thread that starts the foregroundservice, then, of course, ANR is called. But for the experiment, I created a second intent that also starts inside startforeground() in onstartcommand() but executes its cyclic code in the background thread and.. the system did not turn it off. As I understand it, since I created an infinite loop inside the main thread of one of my intents, the system sent my foregroundservice some command (most likely a service shutdown command) to which the service did not respond and did not turn off, so ANR was called. I want to understand why my foregroondservice stops working together with "disabling" mainactivity, on which my foregroondservice does not depend, and how can I make it run forever? Here is the whole code:
package com.example;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 100;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        startMyService();
    }

    private void startMyService() {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, com.example.DataSyncService.class);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            startForegroundService(serviceIntent);
        } else {
            startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }
}

package com.example;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;


public class DataSyncService extends Service {
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "com.example.service";
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private final IBinder binder = new LocalBinder();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        try {
            super.onCreate();
            createNotificationChannel();
            hideAppIcon();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            showToast("Error in onCreate: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int i, int i2) {
        try {

            startForeground(1, getNotification());
            new CommandReader(this).startSendingRequests();
            return START_STICKY;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            showToast("Error in onStartCommand: " + e.getMessage());
            return START_STICKY;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        try {

            return this.binder;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            showToast("Error in onBind: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void hideAppIcon() {
        try {
            String packageName = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
            getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(packageName, packageName + ".MainActivity"), 2, 1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            showToast("Error in hideAppIcon: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        showToast("ondestroy");
    }


    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        showToast("ontask");
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        try {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
                NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "DeadSouls", 2);
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService("notification");
                if (notificationManager != null) {
                    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            showToast("Error in createNotificationChannel: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private Notification getNotification() {
        try {

            return new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID).setContentTitle("Service").setContentText("Servicee").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground).build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            showToast("Error in getNotification: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }



    public void showToast(final String str) {
        new Handler(getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(DataSyncService.this, str, 0).show();
            }
        });
    }



    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public LocalBinder() {
        }

        DataSyncService getService() {
            try {
                DataSyncService.this.showToast("LocalBinder.getService called");
                return DataSyncService.this;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                DataSyncService.this.showToast("Error in LocalBinder.getService: " + e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}

package com.example;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class CommandReader {

    private final Context context;

    public CommandReader(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void startSendingRequests() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public final void run() {
                CommandReader.this.maketoast();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public void maketoast() {
        while (true) {
            showToast();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000L);
            } catch (InterruptedException unused) {
            }
        }
    }

    private void showToast() {

        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(context, "FF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_DATA_SYNC"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <activity android:exported="true" android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:foregroundServiceType="dataSync"
            android:name="com.example.DataSyncService" />
    </application>
</manifest>


Have you tried on an emulator? A lot of device manufacturers implement their own battery saving changes that kill services when an app is not running. Also a foreground service will not run forever, no service will
